# Using use-sound in React and Gatsby.js - How to stop audio playing on route change?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, html5-audio, reach-router

I'm building an audio component in Gatsby.js where the user can play/pause an audio file which is sourced via props.

Here's my example audio.js file, using a test.mp3 file which works fine.

```
import React from "react";
import test from '../../../audio/test.mp3';

import useSound from 'use-sound';

const Pause = ({ stop }) => {
  return (
    <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="68"
    height="60"
    viewBox="0 0 68 60"
    className="button"
    onClick={()=>stop()}
    >
    <g fill="none" fillRule="evenodd" stroke="none" strokeWidth="1">
      <g fillRule="nonzero">
        <g>
          <path
            fill="#1D1D1B"
            d="M33.58.536L15.875 16.77H2.017C.903 16.77 0 17.66 0 18.757v22.488l.006.148c.077 1.028.948 1.838 2.01 1.838h13.859L33.58 59.464c1.29 1.182 3.392.281 3.392-1.454V1.99c0-1.735-2.102-2.636-3.392-1.454zm-.643 6.016v46.895L18.042 39.791l-.129-.109a2.037 2.037 0 00-1.245-.424H4.033V20.741h12.635c.51 0 1-.19 1.374-.532L32.937 6.552z"
          ></path>
          <path
            fill="#1A1919"
            d="M67.1749541 22.0358335L64.3663191 19.2271985 56.402 27.191 48.4379862 19.2271985 45.6293512 22.0358335 53.593 30 45.6293512 37.9641665 48.4379862 40.7728015 56.402 32.808 64.3663191 40.7728015 67.1749541 37.9641665 59.211 30z"
          ></path>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
    </svg>
  );
};

const Play = ({ play }) => {
  return (
    <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="70"
    height="60"
    viewBox="0 0 70 60"
    className="button"
    onClick={play}
    >
    <path
      fill="#1d1d1b"
      d="M33.58.536c1.29-1.182 3.392-.281 3.392 1.454v56.02c0 1.735-2.102 2.636-3.392 1.454L15.875 43.23H2.017c-1.063 0-1.934-.81-2.011-1.838L0 41.244V18.756c0-1.097.903-1.986 2.017-1.986h13.858zm-.643 6.016L18.042 20.209a2.034 2.034 0 01-1.374.533L4.033 20.74v18.517h12.635c.453 0 .891.15 1.245.424l.129.109 14.895 13.656zm27.15.098c13.356 12.59 13.168 33.228-.274 46.306l-.412.394-2.79-2.869C68.7 39.087 69.102 21.018 57.65 9.855l-.351-.336zm-7.272 4.537c10.879 10.142 10.725 26.78-.218 37.309l-.335.317-2.773-2.884c9.514-8.87 9.834-22.907.836-31.588l-.284-.27zm-7.185 6.56c7.408 6.665 7.497 17.5.265 24.262l-.265.243-2.72-2.932c5.66-5.092 5.745-13.223.253-18.406l-.253-.234z"
    ></path>
    </svg>
  );
};

const Player = () => {
  const [play, { stop, isPlaying }] = useSound(test);
  return (
    <div className="player">
      {isPlaying ? <Pause stop={stop} /> : <Play play={play} />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Player;
```

And then imported in on a generic page.

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import Player from "../components/molecules/audio/audio"


export default function Introduction({data}) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      This is my audio component below.
      <Player />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

The difficulty I'm having is stopping the audio when I change Route to another page in React. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like [use-sound](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-sound) is loading a global (Howler) and doesn't clean up after itself, so I suspect the easiest way to do this without using a different approach is going to be calling `stop` in a `useEffect` cleanup:

```
const Player = () => {
  const [play, { stop, isPlaying }] = useSound(test);

  // call `stop` on “dismount”
  useEffect(() => stop, [])

  return (
    <div className="player">
      {isPlaying ? <Pause stop={stop} /> : <Play play={play} />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

For clarity, here's what that largely unpacks to in the conventional format:

```
// these two are largely equivalent
useEffect(() => stop, [])

useEffect(() => {
  // do nothing on “mount”

  // return cleanup function
  return () => {
    stop()
  }
}, [])
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @coreyward

This worked for me in the end.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      stop();
    };
  }, [stop]);
```

Comment: That's effectively my answer since `() => stop` is functionally identical to `() => { return () => { stop() } }`. Normally you'd accept my answer instead of re-answering it yourself with the solution I provided.

Comment: OK apologies Corey, that has been amended.